# Space in attribute value gets replaced by " (quotation mark)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I insert a string with whitespace as an attribute value it gets replaced by a quotation mark.
For example,

```
@foreach (string file in files) {
    <div class="item active">
       <img class="img-responsive" src=@file alt="Book cover">
    </div>
}
```

It gets rendered as

```
<div class="item active">
    <img class="img-responsive"     src="c:\users\raghav" sharma\documents\visual="" studio="" 2013\projects\bookhive\bookhive\content\images\0007282311-1.jpg="" alt="Book cover">
</div>
```

It's really pissing me off. I don't know why this happens I've searched the whole internet but got nothing so far.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. I want to know that what @file contains defaultly (value of file in model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes around the value e.g.

`src="@file"`

That should wrap the value of `@file` like so:

`src="c:\users\raghav sharma\documents\visual="`

The Razor parser will be intelligent enough to spot the `@file` in the quotes and replace that will the value of `@file`.